# How do i fetch and merge work using my forked Bitbucket repo?

Tags: git, bitbucket

I don't know if I am saying correctly, but here goes.

My team is using bitbucket for our work. i have made the main repo which my team forks from, now one of the teammates just pushed some work(made pull request), ive merge it in the main repo, now i need to get the changes from the fork, how do i do it?

I tried to add the main repo and a remote add, but it doesnt seem to be working. I use svn/git at work and i have no trouble, but bitbucket is confusing to me.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Don't fully understand what you have or what's missing but here is my advice:

Clone the repo from bitbucket locally

```
git clone [bitbucket address]
```

then, whenever there is a change and you want to pull

```
git pull [bb address]
```

If you already have a clone but not the remote bitbucket repo added do so by

```
git remote add bb [bitbucket address]
```

then you can pull again by

```
git pull bb
```

where bb is the remote alias.

If you already have all that you just want to pull (and merge which is another problem you might encounter)

```
git pull bb
```

Comment: very weird, i did the same exaact thing before it kept complaining, now it works lol. thanks!

Answer (score 1):

I also use bitbucket, following works for me to push the changes

```
git add <file/folder>
git commit -m "Checkin in code"
git push -u origin master
```